# Entityforms validation

Tags: forms

What is the best way to add some validation to the fields in an Entityforms form? I did some googling can't find any good answers.

Thanks, 
Jonathan

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone else finds this.

You can use [Entity Rules](https://drupal.org/project/entity_rules) This was made for Entityform 1.x but could be used with 2.x

You could probably also use [Field Validation](https://drupal.org/project/field_validation) if you didn't want to use Rules.